# Time Delta in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, split

I am having two datetime values.

I am trying to get the result where the given time will be splitted in the given slots.

time_delta(from_date, to_date, time_lapse)

Ex:

```
from_date = '2018-05-18 00:00:00'
to_date = '2018-05-18 23:59:59'
time_delta(from_date, to_date, 1.hour)
```

Expecting the response:
Response = `[ '2018-05-18 12 AM', '2018-05-18 1 AM', '2018-05-18 2 AM', ... '2018-05-18 12 PM', '2018-05-18 1 PM', ... '2018-05-18 10 PM', '2018-05-18 11 PM']`

Not sure how to get such response.

Answer (score 0):

```
def time_delta(from_date, to_date, step)
  current_date = from_date
  dates = []
  while current_date <= to_date
    dates << current_date
    current_date += step
  end
  dates
end
```

Comment: string<->time transformations are missing, but let this be their homework.

Comment: Don't forget to DateTime.parse the dates